# Laravel - Mail::send is not asynchronous

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My UI gets stalled when I mail my clients using `Mail::send()`.

How can I asynchronously send emails using `Mail::send()` in Laravel 5
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Mail::queue`. Please refer this document https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail

Answer (score 0):

Sending an email can have drastic impact on your response time. For better user experience and preventing long page load time, you should queue your emails. Queuing helps prevent the stalling that you're experiencing as the mails get sent to a queue to be processed in the background. This stops your code from waiting for the email to be sent to continue execution.

Laravel supports mail queuing out of the box with multiple driver support. You can read about queueing and it's implementation here.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#sending-mail

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues

Comment: Thanks will have alook at the links.